# How to send variable to controller not as form input in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, twitter, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am using Spring Boot with Tymeleaf and am fairly new to it. I am using the Twitter API to make an app. I have a list of tweets displayed using `th:each`. When the user clicks the retweet button for a tweet, that particular tweet's id should be sent to the controller as a parameter for the retweet method, so that it can be processed there. The user should not be aware of the id from the front-end.

As of now my only solution is to include the id as a url in an 'a' tag and have it be taken as a path variable using `@PathVariable` in the controller and return the index page which has the list of tweets. This works fine but I do not like this method as the user should not have to leave the page and I may later prefer use a modal. Basically I want to know of a way to send the id to the controller without having it displayed in HTML.

index.html

```
 <div class="result" th:each="result : ${results}">
            <h3><a th:href="${result.fromUser}" th:text="${result.user.name}"></a></h3>

            <p th:text="'@' + ${result.fromUser}"></p>
            <span th:text="${result.text}"></span>
            <div id="retweet">
                    <a th:href="'user/' +  ${result.id}">Retwt</a>

            </div>
        </div>
```

Maincontroller.java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "")
public String getUserProfile(Model model) {
    TwitterProfile userInfo = twitterService.getUserProfile();
    List<Tweet> homeTimeline = twitterService.getUserTimeline();
    model.addAttribute("profileImg", userInfo.getProfileImageUrl());
    model.addAttribute("results", homeTimeline);
    return "pages/index";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/user/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String retweet(@PathVariable long id) {
    twitterService.retweet(id);
    return "/";
}
```

Comment: If you want to send a message to the backend without reloading the page, then you have to use JavaScript to send the data. This can be done using JavaScripts XMLHttp, or a framework like JQuery which makes it a bit easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved changing your controller method as bellow and access it using jQuery ajax http GET.

Changing controller to accept ajax request,

```
    @ResponseBody    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String retweet(@RequestBody Long id) {
        twitterService.retweet(id);
        return "/";
    }
```

Change your HTML,

```
 <div class="result" th:each="result : ${results}">
            <h3><a th:href="${result.fromUser}" th:text="${result.user.name}"></a></h3>

            <p th:text="'@' + ${result.fromUser}"></p>
            <span th:text="${result.text}"></span>
            <div id="retweet">
                    <a href="JavaScript:Void(0);" th:onclick="'doRetweet(\'' + ${result.id} + '\');'" >Retwt</a>

            </div>
        </div>
```

JQuery part,

```
                     function doRetweet(userId){
                        var data = JSON.stringify(userId)
                        if (data) {
                            $.ajax({
                                url : '/user',
                                headers : {
                                    'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
                                },
                                method : 'GET',
                                dataType : 'json',
                                data : data,
                                success : function(data) {
                                    if (data.status == 200) {
                                        // Handle success response
                                    } 
                                },

                                error : function(xhr, status, error) {
                                    // Handle errors here
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I totally forgot about jquery.